# Most natural way of saying something is better than or best

Tags: words

Most natural way of saying something is better than or best.

> 1. This picture is the best
> 2. This picture is better than ...

The translations I see on Google are **ベスト** and **べター**. Looking for a way how Japanese would compare things.

Thanks!

Comment: @Bhupen Google translator is not the best when studying japanese, so I recommend you study a bit somewhere else. For instance: http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/comparison

Comment: @Felipe Oliveira Yeah figuring that out now :D. So what would be a good online dict. to use?

Comment: I thought we were in a 鉄拳 forum or something lol  @Bhupen the site I mentioned is pretty good IMO. But you gotta find what works best for you :)

Comment: I have found jisho.org to be really reliable as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The katakana words you found are not used in comparisons very often (if at all).

---

I'll start with `best`.  You won't find a direct linear translation. To get the same meaning in Japanese, I would call things `number one`.  Here is an example:

> 今まで食｛た｝べたハンバーグなかで、このレストランのハンバーグが一番｛いちばん｝だ。
>   Of all the hamburgers I've eaten, the hamburgers from this store are the best. (literally: 'they are number one')

If you add an adjective after 一番｛いちばん｝ you can get `the most ___` as your meaning instead.

> 一番｛いちばん｝美味｛おい｝しい食｛た｝べ物｛もの｝。
>   Most delicious (or tasty) food.

I would be careful with this one though, as it is a superlative.  English speakers use superlatives all the time, but we don't take the meaning literally.  In Japanese, it is more likely that they will take the meaning literally (depends on the situation), so be careful in its use.  I would use the next construct more.

---

`Better` is a construction that compares something to something else.  There many ways to compare, but `___の方｛ほう｝がいい` will be the best for beginners.  You'll learn more ways to compare over time, but you will be able to express your ideas with this phrase quite well

> マクドは美味しい｛おいしい｝けど、モスバーガーの方｛ほう｝がいいと思｛おも｝う。
>   McDonalds is tasty, but I think Mos Burger is better.

As with the last example, you can also use this construct to modify an adjective in the following manner `___の方が(adjective)`.

> でも、中国{ちゅうごく｝の町｛まち｝の方｛ほう｝が汚｛きたな｝いでしょう？
>   But Chinese towns are more dirty, right?

I think that as far as comparisons go, `___の方｛ほう｝がいい` will be your best bet, and it will be used so much that it will come in handy very quickly.

Comment: The gist of this answer is fine, but the first sentence is false: ベスト is in fact very commonly used in similar ways as 一番 (e.g., ここに揃っている商品の中ではこれがベストだ)

Comment: Is there a general way to say "more than any other"? Something like 全てより?

Comment: @Radiodef （他の）どれよりも